# Trouble with inserting the second record data into the database

Tags: asp-classic

Users can add multiple fields in the form.

When they submit the form, I need to receive this data, save it in the database and redirect users back to the form page.

However, only the first data is inserted into the database and users are redirected back to the form page immediately.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
For i = 0 to Request.Form("totalGRADES")
    If Request.Form("x") = "p" AND Session("Access") = "On" Then

        classYEAR   = Clean(Request.Form("classYEAR" & i))
        gpa         = Clean(Request.Form("gpa" & i))

        Call AddGrades (classYEAR, gpa)

    End If
Next


Sub AddGrades (classYEAR, gpa)

    SQL = "INSERT INTO grades (memberid, classYEAR, gpa, dateENTERED) VALUES ('"& Session("MEMBERID") &"', '"& classYEAR &"', '"& gpa &"', '"& FormatDateMySQL(NOW) &"')"
    Set objAddGRADE = objConn.execute(SQL)

Response.Redirect Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")   

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `Response.Redirect Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")` from `Sub` and place it after `Next` statement.
BTW, Your code is insecure. Before passing form fields value to SQL, You need check it for `'` and so on...

Comment: Thank you so much VMV, I should not have missed it. BTW, clean function checks for SQL injection.